# Retrieving DataSet from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, database

```
static public DataSet GetDataSet(string strSql)
{
    DataSet ds = new  DataSet();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DAL.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

This is the code I use to retrieve a dataset, I get the error that the object name (the certin table) is unknown. The path is supposed to be working:

```
static private string path;
//static private string connectionString;
static public string Path
{
    set
    {
        DAL.path = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return DAL.path;
    }           
}

static private string ConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True", DAL.Path);
    }
}
```

It would really be great if I could get help its for a school project for the next few days.

Comment: In which line do you get this error?

Comment: Well you'd get a connection failure if the path was rubbish, so given you get table not found that suggests the valid db isn't the one you want.

Comment: on this line dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

Comment: What is your sql express server instance name? You can refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx to get the instance name.

Comment: Could you show the sql text passed in to the GetDataset method. I suppose that something is wrong there

Comment: I think your SQL query was wrong.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ProblemsTbl" very basic query... hard to get wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have used correct table Name in the SQL query.

Table name in SQL query and Attached db should be same.

Comment: If I enter a page that uses this function it crashes,if i go to a diffent page and from there redirect to that page it works perfectly

Comment: Could you please provide us the SQL query used and The table name on which you are firing the query  ?
Also value of DAL.path which is generated while debugging in both the scenario which you have mentioned above.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM ProblemsTbl" - query